PNG image encoded in base64 shows in IE and doesn't show in chromium browsers
I have that html code with base64 image:


<div class="Section">
  <img
    style="position:relative; top:10;"
    src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgBAMAAACBVGfHAAAAElBMVEXAwMBuAgL/W1v/AAC9AAD///+MLGppAAAAAXRSTlMAQObYZgAAAGR6VFh0RGVzY3JpcHRpb24AAHicU1ZwcnX39FNw8fXkKkstKs7Mz1OwVTDRM+DiLM9MKckAcoyNuDgzUjPTM0ognOKSxJJUIFNJiYszJbOoGMg05OJMK0rMTYWwlRVc/VzAJgIAmrcYC32rgUMAAABSSURBVCiRY2CgGxCEAhifESYgAFMgpAQGijAlghC+kglCwDQUBFwQAqEYAsYgQJoACAS74LEFrIM0AUyHodmi7AIBcAERCN8RJoARQBhBSHsAACkTIuA37HJZAAAAAElFTkSuQ"
  />
</div>



It shows as it should in IE, but doesn't decode properly in chromium browsers, including microsoft edge.
Tried to check the difference of base64 strings in chrome and IE, but didn't notice anything, so I have no ideas

The "Q" at the end is invalid. IE must be ignoring it where Chromium is more picky

How you understood that?

I used the base64 CLI tool to decode then re-encode. The result was the same string minus the last character

You can also validate the string using these suggestions
